# Bootstrap drop down menu Bar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

OK this is driving me nuts.  I had the navbar set up and working well on my test site: http://nissidesign.com/FeedMySheep/

But when I uploaded it on its own space, the navigation is not working.  The drop downs don't work and when you collapse the menu on small screen, it does not open.  What am I not getting here?  the new site is at http://fresnofeedmysheep.com

Same thing on both

Comment: I have added the answer, I cannot help more without the actual code!

Comment: Don't know how to add code, because it tells me it is too long.  problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

In this site (https://nissidesign.com/FeedMySheep/) when we click on the dropdown it adds a class of `.open` to the `<li class="dropdown">`.

Whereas in this site (https://www.fresnofeedmysheep.com/) when we click on the dropdown it is firing the click event but the class of `.open` is not added to the `<li class="dropdown">`.

---

If you go on this site (https://www.fresnofeedmysheep.com/) and using the **Developer Tools** add a class of `.open` any of the `<li class="dropdown">`. You will see that the dropdown opens.

So the problem is there where we add the `.open` to `<li class="dropdown">` on click.

---

Comment: Did not work for me.  When I added open to the <li> and refreshed the page, they ALL stayed open.

Comment: Thank you!  I got it.  Was a combo between the JS path and added a different JS at the bottom of the page.  Still don't know why it was working on one site and not another.